# Why does the Apple-generated strong password autofill have no text?

Tags: ios, passwords, uitextfield, uitextinput

When using Apple's text input to generate a strong password, my text field is empty when I tap on `Use string password`.

I'm using a UITextField with the content type of `newPassword` and everything works well, until I tap `Use strong password` from Apple's UI. When I do that, the input remains empty. It never actually shows the generated password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because on my UITextField `.clearsOnBeginEditing` was set to true. Whenever the text input became first responder it would clear the existing text, including the Apple generated strong password.

Not sure how to have `.clearsOnBeginEditing` and use a Apple generated password though.